# Collecting after filtering a stream with Java 8

Tags: java, java-stream

i have a list of DTOs, these dtos contains a list of tags. I'm searching to find dtos that contain 2 tags each with its own key and value. this code will work - but it would only find first on the inner filters, i would like to collect instead of finding the first, in case there is more than one object with that criteria

```
List<myDTO> responsesList = getAllData(parameters);
List<myDTO> result = responsesList.stream()
                    .filter(d ->
                            d.getData().getTags().stream()
                                .filter(t ->  t.getKey().equals(key1) && t.getValue().equals(value1))
                                .findFirst().isPresent())
                    .filter(d ->
                            d.getData().getTags().stream()
                                .filter(t -> t.getKey().equals(key2) && t.getValue().equals(value2))
                                .findFirst().isPresent())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

what am I missing to collect a collection instead of the `findFirst().isPresent()`? if I do `Collect(collectors.toList)` I get an error message like "inference variable T has incompatible bounds"?

Comment: The `findFirst` applies only to the tags, not the actual DTO objects.

Comment: Are you sure the code in your question is the actual code that's generating that compiler error?  list.stream().filter(…).filter(…).collect(Collectors.toList()) pretty much has to return a List of the same type as the original List.  The actual Predicates passed to `filter` won't change that.

Comment: I think your code is just fine. You are filtering the DTOs *by* filtering the tags ... and that tag-filter is looking to see that there is at least one tag that matches `key1=value1`. Can you be more specific about why you think this is a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not actually clear what do you want. If you need to collect all the `myDTO` objects which have both key1/value1 tag and key2/value2 tag, then your code already works. You can just shorten it as `filter(predicate).findFirst().isPresent()` could be replaced with `anyMatch(predicate)`:

```
List<myDTO> result = responsesList.stream()
                .filter(d ->
                        d.getData().getTags().stream()
                            .anyMatch(t -> t.getKey().equals(key1) && t.getValue().equals(value1)))
                .filter(d ->
                        d.getData().getTags().stream()
                            .anyMatch(t -> t.getKey().equals(key2) && t.getValue().equals(value2)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can also join both `filters` into single predicate, though this is a matter of taste:

```
List<myDTO> result = responsesList.stream()
                .filter(d ->
                        d.getData().getTags().stream()
                            .anyMatch(t -> t.getKey().equals(key1) && t.getValue().equals(value1))
                        &&
                        d.getData().getTags().stream()
                            .anyMatch(t -> t.getKey().equals(key2) && t.getValue().equals(value2)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you actually want to collect matching tags, you may need a `flatMap`:

```
List<myTag> result = responsesList.stream()
                .flatMap(d -> d.getData().getTags().stream())
                .filter(t -> t.getKey().equals(key1) && t.getValue().equals(value1) ||
                             t.getKey().equals(key2) && t.getValue().equals(value2))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```